# Similar distance pairs

Tags: algorithms

There are two lists of 2D coordinates with the same length. Now I want each element of list 1 to form a pair with an element of list 2, in such a way that the distance between both elements are similar.

E.g. http://m.imgur.com/pkqLfNq green is list 1 and pink is list 2

I would like An algorithm for this problem that can be programmed in JavaScript

Thank you

Comment: One algorithm is to try all $n!$ matchings where $n$ is the number of green points, compute the standard deviation of each one, and choose the smallest.  This is not very efficient, but the problem has the combinatorial flavor of an NP-hard problem.

Comment: what does mean "2D coordinates with the same length" ? the example seems to be 1D

Comment: Sorry, I Mean 2 list with the same length, thus containing the same amount of elements. And 2d I mean like (x,y) but I kept the example simple

Comment: did you found a solution ? finally, does this question mean how to minimize the whole paths length difference with the mean ? there is a kind of sort function to check if it converges ( even slowly )